# Terminal/iTerm2 window name on macOS: how to un-stick SSH to show next process?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, window, title

I'm wondering whether others have experienced this issue (below in bold) and/or found a workaround: in macOS (any version that I've tried which provides Terminal access, so I'm assuming OS X on up; on any hardware), a Terminal or iTerm2 window gets named with the active top-level process until it ends or you quit it. Expected behavior for all systems with Terminal access, right?

When using SSH in Terminal or iTerm2 on macOS, the name of the remote machine populates the top of the window. Also expected. The unexpected comes when you exit out of the SSH session, and the name of the remote machine you had SSH'ed into persists in the window banner; there is no more visibility in the window banner of your current top-level running process, until and unless you close the window (losing some access to command history), and open a new window.

I've never seen this process-stuck behavior on the banner of a Terminal window in any other OS; various forms of Terminal on Linux distros exit out of SSH and get back to showing the top-level running process fine, as does CMD or PowerShell in Windows. What's going on with macOS, and why has this behavior never been addressed, at least as for as my limited DuckDuckGo-fu (or !G-fu) can find?

Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone have a workaround? Do we need to bend Tim Cook's ear? That'd be, forgive the pun, fruitful…

Insight welcome. Thanks!